# Saving Image Retrieved from InputStream locally

Tags: android, inputstream, drawable

I used the following code to retrieve an image from a url and display it within an activity.

```
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url[0]).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "imagename");
    ImageView...
```

Now I want to save this image (Drawable d) locally when a user clicks a button so I can display it again in another activity (along with a few other tasks).

I'd like to store it within the app folder itself rather than on the SD card.

How would I do this?

Thanks!
Shannon

Comment: Look at my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

Comment: Thanks.. This seemed to work.  I didn't get an error in the LogCat indicating there was a problem saving the file.  If I wanted to access the file in another activity how do I reference this file and where did it save it (drawable, raw, etc)?

Comment: Thanks, this code worked perfectly to save the file!  I figured how to reference the file once saved by opening it with "InputStream is = openFileInput("imagenamesaved");" and then handling it like I did above in my question.  This is working!  Awesome Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

For Drawable save as image, I am doing this,

```
Bitmap image_saved=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon);

FileOutputStream fOut=new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+fileName); 
// Here path is either sdcard or internal storage
image_saved.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
image_saved.recycle(); // If no longer used..
```

But Actually, **I suggest you to Instead of going from an InputStream to a Drawable, go from an InputStream to a File, then load the image out of the file. So you can save first file and use it in loading Image.**

And for url Inputstream to write file look at this tutorial [Save binary file from URL](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/SavebinaryfilefromURL.htm)

Comment: Thanks!  I like the suggestion regarding downloading the image locally and just displaying it as needed... The tutorial is great.  I have a couple questions... 1) where does the file save itself (drawable, raw, etc). If the answer is where I want... where do you recommend and how do I reference the path to local directories (drawable, raw, etc)  2) How do I reference the file at run time?  Do I just have a file already located locally that I overwrite with at runtime?

Comment: Nevermind! I got the answer.  It was a misunderstanding on my part on how files are handled at runtime!  DDMS helped me to under the file structure and where my files were being saved!

Comment: Nice, for you got answer of your question by yourelf. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please view this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#InternalCache) for how to save cached files and this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for general internal file storage.

Answer (score 0):

Tested snippet :

```
InputStream is=null;
            try {
                is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "profile_picture");
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
            FileOutputStream out=null;
            try {
                out = getActivity().getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("profile_picture", getActivity().getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```